# Do conditional statements in shaders come at a higher cost?

Tags: opengl, webgl, shader, gpu

I can use conditional statements to minimize average reads from texture, but if conditional statements come at a high cost like with CPUs (that prevent predicting etc), it might result in a complex code that has no gain or even it has less efficiency. Do they come at a higher cost?

Comment: "*come at a high cost like with CPUs (that prevent predicting etc)*" Branches on CPUs don't prevent prediction. Prediction is *for* branching; that's where it gets used. The CPU takes a guess at which branch is more likely to be taken and starts executing instructions along that branch.

Comment: General rule of thumb following is order or cost from less to high  1. Condition based on variable evaluated at compile time 2. Condition based on uniform passed to shader 3. Condition based on variable evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, yeah, I meant that failed prediction comes at a cost.

Answer (score 3):

> Do conditional statements in shaders come at a higher cost?

As always: it depends. Nothing is for free. Modern GPUs can do quite well with branching based on uniform conditions. What really hurts is non-uniform control flow, which will naturally lead to not utilizing all available shader ALUs. With nested conditionalsand/or loops, you can easily end up with a singe active core per SIMT group, which means throwing away 31/32 to 63/64 of the potential computational power.

> I can use conditional statements to minimize average reads from texture

Be careful with texture sampling in non-uniform control flow. As per the spec, this will lead to *undefined values*. The problem here is that you screw up the calculation of the derivatives for the texcoords, so the GPU can't descide if it needs to use the magnification or minification filter, as well as which mipmap level to use.

Comment: "*What really hurts is non-uniform control flow*" On modern GPUs, what really hurts is non-*localized* non-uniform control flow. If your control flow is non-uniform, but aligned on block boundaries, or has relatively few blocks that have non-uniform control flow, then performance will be fine.

Comment: What about these alternatives, would you suggest them?
http://theorangeduck.com/page/avoiding-shader-conditionals

Comment: @user5515: It's hard to evaluate optimization alternatives to an abstract hypothetical. Performance optimization has to be based around each specific case; you can't just throw together a few rules of thumb and move on. I can construct cases where a condition on a seemingly non-uniform value would be perfectly performance friendly. And vice-versa.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas  I understand, but I'm asking because I can't find a tool that will show me the actual performance hit, or gain, except when frames start to drop (in WebGL at least). So only some custom benchmark that will aim to overload the GPU until it drops frames might be the only performance measure tool, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user5515: ... welcome to rendering optimization ;) My point is that we can only give you a useful answer for *specific* cases, not for general hypotheticals. There are too many variables for a general solution to work. There's no single broad advice we can give you except "try stuff and profile."

Comment: @Nicol Bolas "try stuff and profile."  Profile how?

Comment: @user5515: The old-fashioned way: devise a test case and benchmark it. Try different ways of implementing them, and benchmark them.